# Startup Notepad with Cygwin's cron

Tags: cron, cygwin, foreground, notepad

I want to have notepad started up with Cygwin's cron.  I can run a script from cron, so I know that cron is working.  However when I want to start notepad, it won't launch the program in the foreground.  I have attempted to start it up on the crontab in various ways without success. Here is cronevents:

```
CMD (C:\windows\notepad.exe)
CMD (notepad.exe &)
CMD (C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -c "C:\windows\notepad.exe &")
CMD (C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -c "C:\windows\notepad.exe")
CMD (C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -c "C:\windows\notepad.exe" &)
CMD (C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -c notepad &)
CMD (C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -c C:\windows\notepad.exe &)
CMD (notepad &^I)
CMD (notepad )
```

Here is what may current crontab -l looks like:

```
$ crontab -l
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.KhwbuL8Q3t installed on Thu Feb  9 08:56:32 2012) 
# (Cron version V5.0 -- $Id: crontab.c,v 1.12 2004/01/23 18:56:42 vixie Exp $)
#My Crontab file


*/1 * * * *     notepad
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want to launch notepad from cron?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following as the cron command?

```
cmd /C "C:\windows\notepad.exe"
```